Error in Ubuntu
I have both Windows 11 and Ubuntu on my PC. I usually turn on the PC and then I could choose which operating system to use. Yesterday I turned on the PC and I wanted to use Ubuntu, but after choosing it in the menu I get this error message.
The PC gives me the possibility to use the recovery mode, but I don't know what to do.


Please post a screenshot of the screen that asks you to go to recovery mode

@ArchismanPanigrahi https://imgur.com/s6dBwli
